# Form whose top has to be aligned with an image in the background

Tags: css, html, forms, layout

I have received a design to implement for a page with a form, where the bottom of the top part of the form has to be aligned with an image in the background, like this:

[image: Page with form designs]

As you see, there is a "form section" after the "form top". The bottom of "form top" and the top of "form section" are aligned with the bottom of the background image. There is also a quote by John Doe over the background image, which is kept to the right and contained in it. There is also another section with "A title" and links that is kept also to the right but below the background image.

I didn't receive the design for mobile, so for small screens I am just setting `display: none` on the quote and pushing the section with "A title" and links below the form.

My question is, what is the best markup and CSS to achieve this?

### Things I've tried:

1. I first tried dividing the page in two sections, top and bottom, and then pushing the form up with a negative margin. The markup (a very, very simplified version of it) looked like:

   ```html
   <div class="top">
     <div class="quote">A quote</div>
   </div>  

   <div class="bottom">
     <form>form inputs here</form>
     <div class="links-section"><a>A link</a><a>Another link</a></div>
   </div>
   ```

   The styles looked something like:

   ```html
   .top { position: relative; background-image: url(blah); }
   .quote { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; etc. }    

   form { display: inline-block; width: 50%; position: relative; top: some negative unit; }
   .links-section { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }
   ```

   Again, a very simplified version with only the relevant code. "Some negative unit" is what I was tweaking in order to align the form and the background image.

   With such approach, i.e., keeping the form constrained to the light green area, I really struggled to keep things aligned across browsers and across different screen sizes with the bottom of the image. By "things" I mean the bottom of the "form top" and the top of the "form section", which should be aligned with the bottom of the background image. I guess this is like trying to create a pixel perfect design, which I consider very difficult if not impossible.
2. So I tried a different approach, but I feel like it is a bit nasty. The approach is, to make the form the same size of the page, and define the top and bottom sections INSIDE of the form. A very simplified version of the markup looks like this:

   ```html
   <form>
     <div class="top">
       <div class="form-top">form fields that go in the top</div>
       <div class="quote">A quote</div>
     </div>    

     <div class="bottom">
       <div class="form-bottom">
         form fields that go in the bottom
         includes "form section" and "form bottom" in the image attached
       </div>
       <div class="links-section"><a>A link</a><a>Another link</a></div>
     </div>
   </form>
   ```

   And the styles:

   ```html
   .top { background-image: url(blah); }
   .form-top { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }
   .quote    { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }   

   .form-bottom   { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }
   .links-section { display: inline-block; width: 50%; }
   ```
3. Another approach, which I also find nasty, is to have a markup like the one in approach 2. but with the form fields not being surrounded by a `form` tag, and then have the form tag only surrounding the submit button and pray for the fields to be found and sent when people click the submit button. For example:

   ```html
     <div class="top">
       <div class="form-top">form fields that go in the top</div>
       <div class="quote">A quote</div>
     </div>    

     <div class="bottom">
       <div class="form-bottom">
         form fields that go in the bottom
         includes "form section" and "form bottom" in the image attached

         <form>
           <button type="submit">Submit</button>
         </form>

       </div>
       <div class="links-section"><a>A link</a><a>Another link</a></div>
     </div>
   ```

   It doesn't help that, **when the form is submitted, a thank you message appears in the light green area defined by "form top" + "form section" + "form bottom"**.

Does anybody here have a better idea to markup and style this in a non-nasty way, that works across major browsers and different screen sizes? At the moment I am using approach 2, but I don't feel very proud about that solution.